# How to return only one document on calling a resource endpoint?

Tags: python, eve

I have a collection 'users'. When i call the resource endpoint like `/api/users`, it returns all the documents. If i enable authentication, how could i return only that user document on calling `api/users` based on his/her username?

Or else how could i disable this endpoint `/api/users`  and set authentication only to `api/users/<email>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using User-Restricted Resource Access, you can have a [Dynamic Lookup filter](http://python-eve.org/features.html#dynamic-lookup-filters) using event hooks to filter the `users` results by the `auth_field`. Something like this:

```
from flask import current_app

def pre_GET_users(request, lookup):
    username = current_app.auth.get_request_auth_value()
    # only return user with current username
    lookup["username"] = username

app = Eve()

app.on_pre_GET_accounts += pre_GET_users
app.run()
```